# Get all video mime-types in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mime-types

Using the `mime-types` gems how would I get an array of all of the video mime-types?

Answer (score 1):

[As the source shows](https://github.com/halostatue/mime-types/blob/master/lib/mime/types.rb#L6280), `[]` takes a regex, so you could try:

```
videos = MIME::Types[/^video/]
```

or, you could access Rack's list if you've got that loaded:

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.select{|(k,v)| v.start_with? "video" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following code:

```
require 'mime/types'
puts MIME::Types[/^video/, :complete => true]
```

output:

```
video/3gpp
video/3gpp2
video/x-dl
video/dl
video/x-dv
video/x-fli
video/x-flv
video/x-gl
....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
video_types = []
MIME::Types[/^video/].map{|x| video_types << x.to_s }
```

or just

```
MIME::Types[/^video/].map{|type| type.to_s }
```